# Drawing polygons in 3D

Tags: 3d, javascript, html5, html-canvas, 3d-meshes

I have recently been working on a 3D engine from scratch, using JavaScript and HTML5.  I've successfully created lines (although slightly buggy) and points, but I can't figure out faces. My current code: http://jsfiddle.net/13dylank/crXUC/163/

How do I add filled faces to form the surface of my figure? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: "How do I make a face in 3d?" essentially.

Comment: It's typically a good idea to include the question in your question. No need to link to your code. And tell us what you've tried already and what about it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render 3D I suggest that you take a look at [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).

#### Non-WebGL answer:

If you really want to go without you start by fixing your current bugs before moving on to faces. If you can place a point correctly it shouldn't be hard to make uni-coloured faces. You simply make a [path](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/#paths) between 3 points, and fill it.

Tip: You only need to do translation from 3D to screen coordinates in a single piece of code which you can reuse for points, lines and faces.

#### Problems a bit further down the road:

Polygons that are partly in view, especially those that have a point behind or at the view plane can be tricky to deal with, but it's still reasonably possible if you know what you are doing.

Z-order, that is figuring which surfaces should be on the top, is hell, maybe you can for your specific scenes figure a way to do it reasonably.

Texture is also going to be pretty hard to do well.